# How do i find the quotient and remainder of this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^3 - a^3$ divided by $x - a$

Would really appreciate a step by step explanation of how to find the quotient and remainder because I am still learning this concept.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Presumably, you have not learned the sum of cubes formula.  Have you learned long division?

Comment: Or synthetic division? It'd be very helpful to know what you've tried, and where you are running into trouble.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Answer (score 2):

You should get familiar with [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division) and the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).
Here, the possible rational roots are contained in $a^3$ and, if you worked the problem with synthetic division or found the roots(factors), you would see

$$\frac{x^3-a^3}{x-a}=\frac{(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)}{x-a}=x^2+ax+a^2\quad \text{with no remainder}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a famous factorization called the difference of cubes factorization. It is $c^3-d^3 = (c-d)(c^2+cd+d^2)$. Your numerator is a difference of cubes with $c=x$ and $d=a$. Plugging these values into the factorization, we get $x^3-a^3 = (x-a)(x^2+xa+a^2)$. So, your fraction now becomes $\frac{(x-a)(x^2+xa+a^2)}{x-a}$. The quotient is $(x^2+xa+a^2)$ with no remainder.